# Is there a way to set a width to buffer when calling org-agenda-columns?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, agenda

It would just be nice that the column agenda view would span the whole buffer width. Any ideas?

Comment: Buffers don't have width. What do you mean by "buffer width"? Length of the longest line? Width of the window?

Comment: What I mean is when executing C-c C-x C-c on agenda to visualize the agenda as the column view, this column is to narrow. Is there a way to make it wider?